# pandas replace values condition based on another column

Tags: pandas, if-statement

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
col1 col2
Yes  23123
No   23423423
Yes  34234
No   13213
```

I want to replace values in col2 so that if 'Yes' in col1 then return blank and if 'No' return the initial value

I want to see this:

```
 col1 col2
 Yes  
 No   23423423
 Yes  
 No   13213
```

I have tried this but 'No' is returning None:

```
   def map_value(x): 
      if x in ['Yes']:
         return ''
      else:
         return None

   df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(map_value)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

there are many ways to go about this, one of them is

```
df.loc[df.col1 == 'Yes', 'col2'] = ''
```

Output:

```
col1 col2
Yes  
No   23423423
Yes  
No   13213
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy for this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'col1': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no'], 'col2': [23123,23423423,34234,13213]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col2'] = np.where(df.col1 == 'yes', '', df.col2)
df
```

Answer (score 1):

Created `df` by copying sample data from OP's post and using following command:

```
df=pd.read_clipboard();
df
   col1  col2
0  Yes   23123 
1  No    23423423 
2  Yes   34234 
3  No    13213
```

Could you please try following.

```
m=df['col1']=='No'
df['col2']=df['col2'].where(m,'')
df
```

After running code output will be as follows:

```
  col1 col2
0 Yes
1 No   23423423 
2 Yes  
3 No   13213
```